# Whoever that does not comment is fool

Tags: grammar, pronouns

I would like to know if the following sentence is correct.

> "Whoever that does not comment is a fool."

What I'm trying to imply is the following.

> "If you don't comment you are a fool."

Let me know if it's grammatical or not and if it does not sound awkward. I also have my doubts regarding the word 'that' in the sentence.

Comment: Remove the word "that".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As said in the comment, remove *that* to make the sentence work:

> *Whoever does not comment is a fool.*

If you want to use *that*, you can use something like:

> *People that don't comment are fools.*

(Note the difference when using *don't* in the latter because *people* is a plural noun and the *be* form changes to *are.*)

Comment: Some might say that should be "who" instead of "that": _People who don't comment are fools._

Comment: @J.R. Of course. Actually I use *who* because of formalism, but I used *that* to elighten the OP's question.